# Google Email Client using .Net framework 4.0

Tags: asp.net, email, gmail, smtpclient, smtp-auth

I have created a gmail client using host as smtp.gmail.com and configures all the requires credentials and settings.

I have tested the client by hosting it in my local IIS. It worked great.

Then I hosted the project on public server and tested the client. here I am facing the problem that google stopping the signin and i received a mail saying that "Suspicious sign in prevented".

I have given a strong password and fully qualified email address. still I am getting the same problem.

what might be the cause for problem ?

here is my config file.

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<configuration>
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp from="xxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com">
        <network defaultCredentials="false" host="smtp.gmail.com" port="587" userName="xxxxxxxxxxx@gmail.com" password="xxxxxxxxx" enableSsl="true"/>
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  <system.web>
    <compilation debug="false" targetFramework="4.0"/>
    <httpRuntime/>
  </system.web>
</configuration>
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Maybe your server IP address is blacklisted? There are [several online tools to do a check for that](https://www.google.com/search?q=ip+address+blacklist+check).

Comment: Please refer to http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/26600/gmail-suspicious-sign-in-prevented-message-is-it-legit and http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/39759/does-googles-suspicious-sign-in-prevented-mean-that-my-password-is-compromis. Hope that help